# The constructor SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(int) is undefined for type int

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

SeekToCurrentHandler(int) does not accept now in kafka version 2.7.8
The constructor SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(int) is undefined for type int
what should be the alternative for this?

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(maxFailures));
factory.setConcurrency(afConsumerConcurrencyLevel);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, maxFailures - 1)));
```

> This will retry a delivery up to `maxFailures - 1` times (maxFailures delivery attempts) with a back off of 0 second, instead of the default configuration (FixedBackOff(0L, 9)). Failures are simply logged after retries are exhausted.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.8/reference/html/#seek-to-current